# Constraints not respected when loading from XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, xib

So, I have the following XIB

[image]

This XIB when loaded as a tableviewcell looks like this

[image]

I've since decided that I will not need a TableView, so I changed my XIB class from UITableViewCell to UIView. In a ViewController I added this code to viewDidLoad()

```
var nView = MyChartView.instanceFromNib() as! MyChartView
self.view.addSubview(nView)
```

And I got this as a result

[image]

As you can see, it ignores the margins and continues to right side (ignore the red color since I was using it to try and debug the problem. No chart data is not the problem either). I've printed the xib's frame width and I've seen that it's quite a bit bigger than the screen size, but I've not been able to fix it. Anyone can figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a subView programmatically, you should also add constraints between the subView and its superView

```
var nView = MyChartView.instanceFromNib() as! MyChartView
self.view.addSubview(nView)
nView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[nView]|", options:  [], metrics: nil, views: ["nView": nView]))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[nView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["nView": nView]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't constrained the `MyChartView` instance's width, either by specifying an exact size when you add the subview, or programmatically adding constraints between the `MyChartView` instance and its superview. Without doing one or the other of these, the view's dimensions will match whatever they are in the xib.

Comment: I've tried to change MyChartView instance's frame to match the screen, but it made no difference. I'm going to try to add constraints programatically. But why doesn't this problem happen in a tableview?

Comment: I'd suggest making sure that `MyChartView`'s `translateResizingMaskToConstraints` is `false` and that you add constraints (not just set the `frame`) to dictate it's placement within its superview. NRitH is probably right right, that while your NIB might have constraints within itself, it doesn't have any between itself and its superview. If you're still having problems, you'll have to edit your question to show us the constraints you added programmatically and then use view debugger or lldb to show us the constraints at runtime.

Comment: I see what you guys mean, I've accepted Anil Varghese's answer since he had an example. I still don't understand why it worked properly in tableview though. Does it infer the constraints in a tableview?

Comment: @DiogoMartins - A table view adds its cells as subviews (you may instantiate the cell, but the table view adds it to the view hierarchy), so it takes care of setting the constraints between itself and the cell. But if you add the view yourself, then that burden falls on your shoulders.

Comment: @Rob, I see what you mean and now understand. Thanks for the help.